# iPad Browser Tab Carousel - How to cycle browser tabs on iPad automatically?

Tags: ipad, iframe, browser, google-chrome-extension, carousel

I'm looking for a way to automatically cycle through browser tabs on an iPad.
This chrome extension ([tabcarousel](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabcarousel/ddldimidiliclngjipajmjjiakhbcohn?hl=en)) is exactly what I want (every 15 seconds), but it seems extensions aren't available on the iPad with any browser. Why is that?! Can I manually install an extension on the iPad version of Chrome/Safari?

Could I have a page which has say 10 pages each in their own iFrame and javascript which programatically hides and shows one iFrame at a time? That seems like the solution I will try next.
-Would that work on an iPad?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I used the 'VirtualChrome' app, and the tab carousel extension. 
Works well!

Comment: Is this called 'VirtualChrome'?  Because I can't find anything by that name.